# How can get rid of this error, any ideas?

Tags: python, opencv

Help me to get free from this syntax error which I always get after executing it.The syntax seems correct and intact but then also I get the same issue everytime.

```
cv2.circle(im, center_coordinates ,3 ,(0,255,255) , thickness=1, lineType=8, shift=0)
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Every time the error comes as Invalid  Syntax

Comment: Can you show the lines of code before this line? You probably have an unclosed bracket somewhere in there (a guess)

Answer (score 1):

Generally this kind of errors shown on the current line is  because of  the error in the previous line .
so please check thoroughly the previous lines of the code. you must have missed a closed bracket .
I have found nothing wrong in this line.